# Restarting a windows service after a fixed time interval

Tags: c#, windows, service, timer

I am developing a windows service that sends automated e-mail in every 15 minutes. I am using a timer to use the service again after a fixed time interval (15 minutes) but its not working.

```
namespace Mailer
{
  public partial class Mailer : ServiceBase
  {
    System.Timers.Timer createOrderTimer;
    public Mailer()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
      sendmail();  //function to send email.

      createOrderTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();                      
      createOrderTimer.Elapsed += new  System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(createOrderTimer_Elapsed);
      createOrderTimer.Interval = 15000;
      createOrderTimer.Enabled = true;
      createOrderTimer.AutoReset = true;                      
      createOrderTimer.Start();
    }

    protected void createOrderTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
      createOrderTimer.Stop();
      ServiceController controller = new ServiceController("Mailer");
      controller.Start();
    }

    protected void sendmail
    {
      //code to send email.
    }

    protected override void OnStop() {  }
  }
}
```

Initially the email is sent but I want the email sending to be performed in every 15 minutes.

Comment: your interval should be 900000 (ms) for 15 minutes.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici is right, this may help:                              
var myTimer = = new Timer(15 * 60 * 1000); //sets 15 minutes

Comment: Did you consider using a scheduled tasked instead of a service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to change the code like this**

```
namespace Mailer
{
  public partial class Mailer : ServiceBase
  {
    System.Timers.Timer createOrderTimer;
    public Mailer()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
      createOrderTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();                      
      createOrderTimer.Elapsed += new  System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(sendmail);
      createOrderTimer.Interval = 900000; // 15 min
      createOrderTimer.Enabled = true;
      createOrderTimer.AutoReset = true;                      
      createOrderTimer.Start();
    }

    protected void sendmail(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
      //code to send email.
    }

    protected override void OnStop() {  }
  }
}
```

Comment: But using the above code, the service is running continuously, Right?
**What if I want to stop the service for 15 minutes after sending the mail and once the 15 minutes time duration is elapsed, I want to restart the service and send mail.** (Continuous running of service causes wastage of resources, I doubt.) Please reply.

Thanks.

Comment: The service is running continuously and send mail every 15 min. If the service uses a lot of resources, it is necessary to optimize it.